# How to change background-image properties (linear-gradient) with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I pretend to change smoothly the background, so initially I have this CSS block:

```
body {
  transition: background-image 0.5s ease;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #D4145A, #FBB03B);
}
```

Then in my JS I'm trying to update randomly (reading hex values from a JSON file) my background assigning new values with this jQuery method:

```
$.getJSON(gradientsPath, function(json) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*json.length);
  $(document.body).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right top, " + json[rand]["firstColor"] + ", " + json[rand]["secondColor"] + ") !important");
});
```

Also if someone can help me with this minor question: the gradient background works on Safari but in Firefox doesn't seems to work.

Comment: you need to see the jSon data you are using

Comment: oh i see ... add `min-height:100vh` to body ... by the way you cannot apply transition to linear-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste remove the `!important` property

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version, there can be different prefixes for CSS properties.

```
  /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
  background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

$(document.body).css("background-image", "-moz-linear-gradient(to right top, " + json[rand]["firstColor"] + ", " + json[rand]["secondColor"] + ") !important");
```

Credit to [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).